# PHP file access and control

Tags: php, .htaccess, file-access

I know how `.htaccess` works and I can't decide, what rules to write...

I picked up Zend framework's rules:

```
RewriteEngine On
# The following rule tells Apache that if the requested filename
# exists, simply serve it.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
# The following rewrites all other queries to index.php. The
# condition ensures that if you are using Apache aliases to do
# mass virtual hosting, the base path will be prepended to
# allow proper resolution of the index.php file; it will work
# in non-aliased environments as well, providing a safe, one-size
# fits all solution.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)(.+)::\2$
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:BASE}index.php [NC,L]
```

So as it says, everything that does not exist will be redirected to `index.php`, after words I will handle the requested uri, but what about the `php` files that contain only classes where I keep my business logic, its alright - the user will receive blank page, but I want to know how to show error page when it is accessed or more better, how to exclude it from accessing?

Comment: simple: don't put "private" files in publicly accessible areas. if you don't want a file or files of yours to be executable by users, then don't put them in your site's document root. put them somewhere else. PHP won't care. it operates at the filesystem level and can include/require them from anywhere the webserver UID has access.

Comment: Something like private folder, who has block access in .htaccess?

Comment: no. somewhere COMPLETELY outside of your site's document root, so you don't ever have to worry about setting .htaccess protection on it. anything outside of the document root is by definition unreachable by users of your site.

Comment: hmm.. u mean my home directory of my web host for example, i never heard of this, is it a good practice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can insert this rule just below `RewriteEngine On` line:

```
# if request is for a .php file but not index.php then return forbidden
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule \.php$ / [L,NC,R]
```

Comment: but how to notice this in php, so I can show something like, please return home?

Comment: Your PHP won't be even called. But this rule can be changed to redirect to home (see edit)

Comment: By the way, would you like to look above, at Marc B's comment on my question, about having folder outside my document root and if you know if that is good practice?

Comment: Yes that is a good & secure practice if one adapts it at the start of the project. I have myself given few answers recommending it on SO. Though sometimes users resist it since they have already adapted a CMS or built a framework and don't want to move around many files.

Answer (score 0):

You can check with this setting:

```
ErrorDocument 404 http://www.example.com/error/404.html
```

Note: You need to provide path for 404.html. If you are using any framework, then most probably you will find 404.html file inside error model directory.